# Set state from child call back

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a component with a child component that uses an event that runs in the parent.

When I look at the state changes, it appears to succeed, but when on render the value is undefined.

Parent component:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleAnswer = this.handleAnswer.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            showQuestion: false,
            showGetStarted: true,
            correctAnswerTotal: 0,
            question: <Question onAnswer={this.handleAnswer}/>,
            emoji: <EmojiView correctQuestionCount="0"/>
        };


    }

    handleAnswer(result) {
        let emoji = this.state.emoji;       
        if (result === true) {
            let newVal = this.state.correctTotal + 1;

            alert('newVal: ' + newVal);     // updates ------------------------
            this.setState({ correctTotal: newVal }, () => {
                let updatedVal = this.state.correctTotal;
                alert('updatedVal: ' + updatedVal);     // updates
            }); 
        } else {
            this.setState({correctTotal : 0});
        }
    }

  render() {
      let correctTotal = this.state.correctQuestionCount;
      alert('telling it to render with this count:' + correctTotal);
        // correctTotal is undefined here -------------------
      let emoji = <EmojiView correctQuestionCount={correctTotal}/>;

      return (

        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
            </header>
            <p>
                {emoji}
            </p>
        </div>
      );
  }
```

Child component:

```
  questionOneClicked = (user) => {
        let lastQuestion = this.state.lastQuestion;
        if (lastQuestion.correctIndex == 0) {
            // TODO: they got it right!
            var myQuestionModel = new QuestionModel("unused");
            let randomQuestion = myQuestionModel.getRandomQuestion();
            this.setState({lastQuestion: randomQuestion});
            this.props.onAnswer(true);
        } else {
            this.props.onAnswer(false);
        }
  }

  constructor(props, onAnswer) {
        super(props);
        //alert('props: ' + onAnswer);
        var myQuestionModel = new QuestionModel("unused");
        let randomQuestion = myQuestionModel.getRandomQuestion();
        this.state = {
            showQuestion: false,
            showGetStarted: true,
            lastQuestion: randomQuestion,
        };

        this.questionOneClicked = this.questionOneClicked.bind(this);
    }
```

Why is the new state undefined in parent render() even though my alert showed it updated?

Comment: How do you call child component inside parent? Which part of the state exactly is undefined? Which function triggers the unexpected behavior?

Comment: @HagaiHarari: handleAnswer records it successfully, but it wasn't updated in render().  (below) figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating state correctTotal but you are trying to access correctQuestionTotal which isn't set anywhere

Below is how you must use it

```
let correctTotal = this.state.correctTotal;
```

Complete render code

```
render() {
      let correctTotal = this.state.correctTotal;
      alert('telling it to render with this count:' + correctTotal);
        // correctTotal is undefined here -------------------
      let emoji = <EmojiView correctQuestionCount={correctTotal}/>;

      return (

        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
            </header>
            <p>
                {emoji}
            </p>
        </div>
      );
```

On a side note, you must not store component instances in state as they will not be able to undergo props change like they do when in render method. If you declare them in state, they will be treated like static values which only update on state change which I guess you won't be doing

Directly render them in render function like

```
render() {
      let correctTotal = this.state.correctTotal ;
      alert('telling it to render with this count:' + correctTotal);
        // correctTotal is undefined here -------------------

      return (

        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
            </header>
            <p>
                <Question onAnswer={this.handleAnswer}/>
                <EmojiView correctQuestionCount={correctTotal}/>
            </p>
        </div>
      );
```